# sed substitute with quotes and wildcard

Tags: sed, wildcard, substitution

I need to replace `if ($_SESSION['POST']['*']==1){` with `if (isset($_SESSION['POST']['*']) && $_SESSION['POST']['*']==1){`

(I'm using `*` as a wild card)

I've tried `sed -i "s/if ($_SESSION['POST']['.*']/if (isset($_SESSION['POST']['.*']) && $_SESSION['POST']['.*']/g" *.php` and a few other variations without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes...

```
sed "s/\(if (\)\(\$_SESSION\['POST']\['\([^']*\)']\)==1/\1isset(\2) \&\& \$_SESSION['POST']['\3']==1/" file
```

Using double quotes means that the `$` symbols must be escaped, otherwise they will be interpreted as shell variables. The square brackets need to be escaped, otherwise they will be interpreted as the beginning of a range. It's OK to leave the closing square brackets as they are.

In order to capture the key, I have used a character class `[^']*`. This means zero or more characters that are not a single quote.

In the replacement, the captured groups (the parts between parentheses in the match) are referred to using `\1`, `\2`, etc.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file
if ($_SESSION['POST']['foo']==1){
   // do something
}

if ($_SESSION['POST']['bar']==1){
   // do something else
}
$ sed "s/\(if (\)\(\$_SESSION\['POST']\['\([^']*\)']\)==1/\1isset(\2) \&\& \$_SESSION['POST']['\3']==1/" file
if (isset($_SESSION['POST']['foo']) && $_SESSION['POST']['foo']==1){
   // do something
}

if (isset($_SESSION['POST']['bar']) && $_SESSION['POST']['bar']==1){
   // do something else
}
```

By the way it makes the command a few characters shorter if you use extended regexp mode (`-r` or `-E`). In extended mode, the parentheses enclosing capture groups don't have to be escaped but literal ones do, so your command would then be:

```
sed -r "s/(if \()(\$_SESSION\['POST']\['([^']*)'])==1/\1isset(\2) \&\& \$_SESSION['POST']['\3']==1/" file
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I ended up using to do my global replace `sed -i "s/\(if (\)\(\$_SESSION\['POST']\['\([^']*\)']\)/\1isset(\2) \&\& \$_SESSION['POST']['\3']/g" *.php`

Comment: No problem, looks good. Note that unless you expect to see more than one `if` statement on the same line, the global `g` modifier isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` should work:

```
s="if (\$_SESSION['POST']['name']==1){"
sed -r 's/(if +)\((([^=]+)[^\)]+)/\1(isset(\3) \&\& \2/' <<< "$s"
if (isset($_SESSION['POST']['name']) && $_SESSION['POST']['name']==1){
```

**PS:** Use `sed -E` instead of `sed -r` on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another.

This is what we need to produce:

```
Pattern:     if (\$_SESSION\['POST'\]\['\([^']*\)'\]
Replacement: if (isset($_SESSION['POST']['\1']) \&\& $_SESSION['POST']['\1']
```

When quoted in shell level:

```
Pattern:     "if (\\\$_SESSION\['POST'\]\['\([^']*\)'\]"
Replacement: "if (isset(\$_SESSION['POST']['\1']) \\&\\& \$_SESSION['POST']['\1']"
```

Putting it together:

```
sed -i "s|if (\\\$_SESSION\['POST'\]\['\([^']*\)'\]|if (isset(\$_SESSION['POST']['\1']) \\&\\& \$_SESSION['POST']['\1']|g" file
```

Test:

```
# sed "s|if (\\\$_SESSION\['POST'\]\['\([^']*\)'\]|if (isset(\$_SESSION['POST']['\1']) \\&\\& \$_SESSION['POST']['\1']|g" <<'EOF'
> if ($_SESSION['POST']['ABC']==1){
> EOF
if (isset($_SESSION['POST']['ABC']) && $_SESSION['POST']['ABC']==1){
```